# If I create an object in a "with" clause, do I still need to free it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal, with-statement

In my source I see and use often a construction like:

```
with TSQLDataSet.Create(nil) do try
  //Dosomething, get a result from a query.    
finally
  Free;
end;
```

But I also often see the construction:

```
with TSQLDataSet.Create(nil) do begin
  //Dosomething, get a result from a query.    
end;
```

If I create objects with a with contruction, do I need to free them or is that automatic at the end of the with-block?

Comment: I seriously doubt that you see the latter version 'often'.

Comment: @Andreas - good point. But that is possible, if with body makes connects object to some container. Or with not-nil constructor parameter

Comment: If you own it, you have to Free it, or pass the ownership on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `free`.

Because `Class.Create` is just an expression, and Delphi cannot know which expression the resulting value came from.

You can just read VCL sources - there is always explicit `.Free`.

And you can think of non-object example:

```
var r: record .... end;
with r do begin
...
end;
```

If Delphi tried to free everything at `with` end - then it would try to `free` non-object ?

```
with SomeObjectFactory.GetMeAnObject do begin
...
end;
```

Here you create object not by constructor, but by some function. And this function is not different from `TLabel.Font` or `TDataSet.FieldByName`.
Should Delphi `free` it or not here ?

To avoid the risky guesswork and keep it uniform - `with` is just `with`. It is just an alias. Nothing more. It was designed back in 1974 and is does not clone functionality of latest .Net/Scala `Using(x){..}` constructs.

---

What you *maybe* saw were constructs like

```
with TForm.Create(Application) do ...;
with TLabel.Create(MainForm.Panel1) do ...;
```

That is very different - that does insert newly created control as belonging to an owner. The owner would `free` all its owned components when it is `free`d itself. But that does not use `Create(nil)`. And when it still does - then inside the `with` block you would see some explicit call, binding the object to some container/parent (though that is very fragile in case of exceptions between `.Create` and binding).

Comment: I've been broadening my horizon on progamming languages a bit and read about the "using" constructs. And then you come around the "with someobject.create" constructs in your own codebase but without an explicit free, so I was like, is this correct or not. After some further testing, it is indeed that you need to explicitly free the objects you create with a with statement. If you don't it will keep hogging your memory. They don't get reported as memory leaks though.

Comment: Yes, Pascal's lame with is not to be confused with Python's with

Comment: @David i'd not call it "lame". Limited, yes. But not every limited feature is lame.

Comment: @Arioch'The It's not so much that it is limited, more that it's power is too great

Comment: @David really? i wonder... then how you mean to reduce the power without effectively removing it ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to free the object manually. It is *not* true that they are freed automatically at the end of the `with` block. This applies *in general*. If there is something special with the `TSQLDataSet`, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi (Object pascal), C, C++ and many more 3rd generation languages that aren't managed code gives the responsibility of recycling the memory to the programmer. So, in either case you have to be sure that the gained memory is deallocated anywhere in your code.

The first example you gave assumes that the object you created doesn't need to be alive after the end statement. The second examples assumes that the object is created and passed to an other object to be used after the End statement. So the using object should handle the deallocation of memory.

In managed code environments such as Java VM or .Net applications the memory is handled by the environment. The environment senses when there is no reference to an allocated memory piece and frees it whenever it is suitable for the environment.

Comment: It's more complex than that for managed code. If there are objects whcih represent system resources then their lifetime cannot be left to GC. For example file objects which have handles. Hence .net IDisposable and so on. Likewise for database connections.